# How do you produce a CNF from a circular graph with colouring?

Tags: graphs, boolean-algebra, colorings

If you had a circular graph e.g. A->B->C->D->E->A, and a legal coloring system with 3 colours (e.g. Red, Green Blue), where each node is assigned a colour and no node can be connected to another node of the same colour, what is the easiest way go about producing a Conjunctive Normal Form of node states (e.g. AR means A is coloured Red) where the models of the CNF correspond on a one to one basis to a legal colouring of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to solve the more general problem for (undirected) graphs and an arbitrary number of colors. Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and a set of colors $C$, the formula has variables $x(v,c)$ for every vertex $v \in V$ and every color $c \in C$. There are clauses of three kinds:

1. For each vertex $v$, there is a clause $\bigvee_{c \in C} x(v,c)$.
2. For each vertex $v$ and each pair of colors $c,d \in C$, there is a clause $\lnot x(v,c) \lor \lnot x(v,d)$.
3. For each edge $(v,w)$ and each color $c$, there is a clause $\lnot x(v,c) \lor \lnot x(w,c)$.

In words, these clauses state that:

1. Vertex $v$ gets some color.
2. Vertex $v$ gets at most one color.
3. Vertices $v,w$ (which are connected) don't get the same color.

Comment: Thanks! Just to check that I understand this;
If you apply this to the example I gave you'd end up with a CNF along the lines of
(AR v AG v AY) ^ (BR v BG v BY) and so on so that each node has some colour
^ (¬AR v ¬AG) ^ (¬AR v ¬AY) ^ (¬AY v ¬AG) ^ (¬BR v ¬BG) ^ (¬BR v ¬BY) and so on until you had a clause for every two possible colors you could have on each node
And then ^ (¬AR v ¬BR) ^(¬AG v ¬BG) ^ (¬AY v ¬BY) ^(¬BR v ¬CR) and so forth until you had a clause for each color for each vertex

Comment: That's right. ~

Comment: Excellent! If I had the reputation I would give you an upvote, I'll make sure I'll come back to this once I've got the right x)